# AS400 - Passing and calling and RPGLE from a non-ILE Cobol program

Tags: parameters, ibm-midrange, cobol, rpgle

A non-ILE Cobol program is calling and passing parameters to an RPGLE program. The Cobol passes a non-sorted area to RPG, RPG sorts that area with SORTA and returns the sorting area back to the Cobol.

1. Passing parameters between non-ILE Cobol to RPGLE - Is that possible ?
2. What are the constrains (size of parameters, number of parameters) ?
3. Any compilation restrictions ?
4. Any other tips are welcome :)

RPGLE code:

[RPGLE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnJjp.png)

Comment: Welcome @user3604233 to stackoverflow!
Please don't post images with code, but the code directly - images will commonly "fade away" and are not able to be directly read; and in any case I suggest to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn more about how this site works and how to get good answers by good questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is some [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=languages-calling-ile-rpg-programs-procedures). It's ILE COBOL documentation but applies here if you forget about calling procedures.

Comment: @user3604233, please make sure you post the COBOL code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to call an ILE RPG program from any COBOL program.

You can pass up to 255 parameters on a program call.

There are no compilation restrictions. Compile both programs normally.